How to use tidyverse to re-cursively apply a function to return a single result instead of a vector of results?
Using str_replace() function from the stringrpackage as an example.
Supposing you wanted to pair-wise replace an arbitrary vector of patterns with a corresponding vector of replacement values (or a function call) in a given string. You might expect the following code to solve this:
str_replace(string="a1X_", pattern=c("1","a"), replacement=c("0", "A"))

However, this would return a vector of length 2 containing a0X_ and A1X_ instead of the desired result: A0X_-

If your replacement happens to single characters only, you can use chartr
> chartr("1a", "0A", "a1X_")
[1] "A0X_"

or use named vector as the pattern
> str_replace_all("a1X_", setNames(replacement, pattern))
[1] "A0X_"


True, and thanks for contributing. I was unaware of the chartr()option.

The desired result can be accomplished with the purrr package:
reduce2(c("1", "a"), c("0", "A"), \(x,y,z) str_replace(x, y, z), .init="a1X_")

This will also work, if the string is itself a vector like .init=c("a1X_","_X1a"))
